# Electron ipcMain / ipcRenderer Delivery Guarantees

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

Does Electron make any guarantees that (asynchronous) messages sent via ipcMain and ipcRenderer are ...

- delivered at all
- delivered in the exact order they were sent
- delivered only once?

Or do I have to write an additional layer in my application that takes care of all of this? Like sending delivery receipts, adding a sequence field and re-order messages on the recipient side etc.

It would be great if any form of evidence (e.g. documentation) would be provided.